# Preparing form data for a POST request with fetch

Tags: javascript, form, ajax

Acquiring a form’s data for asynchronous POST requests has been a long-standing problem. There is the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) API, but there are still some obstacles when the form’s data is encoded as `x-www-form-urlencoded` (the default).

My current use case deals with arbitrary forms which might encode data either way; hence, I tried to generalize the way I construct the request’s body. Note that it’s intentional the form is submitted as an asynchronous request as the response is going to be rendered inside the current document.

Can this generalization be simplified further?

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', performPostRequest);

/**
 * Handles submit events that are about to perform a POST request.
 *
 * @param {Event} event
 */
function performPostRequest(event) {
  // Prevent the default action of sending a regular POST request.
  event.preventDefault();

  const form = event.target;

  fetch(form.action, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': `${form.enctype}; charset=UTF-8`
    },
    body: constructRequestBody(form)
  })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
}

/**
 * Encodes a form’s data for a POST request’s body.
 *
 * Supported encoding types:
 *
 * - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
 * - `multipart/form-data`
 *
 * @param {HTMLFormElement} form
 * @returns {FormData|URLSearchParams}
 */
function constructRequestBody(form) {
  const formData = new FormData(form);

  if (form.enctype === 'multipart/form-data') {
    return formData;
  }

  const requestBody = new URLSearchParams();

  for (const [name, value] of formData) {
    requestBody.append(name, value);
  }

  return requestBody;
}
```

Comment: (Repost, link fixed)  
"there are still some obstacles when the form’s data is encoded as x-www-form-urlencoded" can you explain? Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38931547/2644192) resolve potential problems?

Comment: @Calak I’m referring to the problem I’m solving in the `constructRequestBody` function: Using a `FormData` object for a POST request with `x-www-form-urlencoded` data. The answer in the link you provided solves the problem, but it is more verbose.

Comment: Does the *relative* verbosity is a real problem if your ending code is more robust and flexible?

Comment: @Calak The solution you linked to is not more robust or flexible than mine.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this generalization be simplified further?

```
return new URLSearchParams(formData)
```

Comment: Oh, great! Since `formData[Symbol.iterator]` returns `formData.entries()`, it can be omitted from that call, too.

Comment: Do you know whether this is implemented in most browsers? I tried Firefox and Chrome and it does work.

Comment: @kleinfreund Have not tried Safari or Edge

Comment: As of writing this comment only IE11 (and below) and some other browsers do not support URLSearchParams. Check here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams